# Create a text file based on position and length

Tags: c#, text

I have a requirement to create a text out put based on position and length of fields. For example

```
Position | Length  |FieldName |Comments
1        |  2      | Code     |1-2 eg:00
3        |  1      |Filler    |3 space filled
```

The value of code and filler comes from a class when i create text file it has to match the above requirements

```
 object o1 = "00";
           object o2 = "00000";
           Console.WriteLine("\"" + o1.ToString().PadLeft(8) + "\"");
           Console.WriteLine("\"" + o2.ToString().PadRight(8) + "\"");  
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What problems are you having? What code do you have thus far?

Comment: And....? Have you done any kind of work and are you willing to show your efforts here? Or are just asking someone to write the code for you?

Comment: I just started with a POC now  //string txt = "Hello World";
            //string txt2 = "Test";
            //string txt3 = "Let's go";

            //string line = String.Format("{0,-15} {1,-10} {2,10}", txt, txt2, txt3);

            //Console.WriteLine(line);
            //Console.ReadLine();

           object o1 = "00";
           object o2 = "00000";
           Console.WriteLine("\"" + o1.ToString().PadLeft(8) + "\"");
           Console.WriteLine("\"" + o2.ToString().PadRight(8) + "\"");  
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: I was looking for a good approach. My thoughts was to create  a template file with Tokens which can be replace through code. I need some suggestions

Comment: Please put your code in the question with an edit. It's unreadable as a comment... IT looks like you are on the right track though (from what I can make of it)!

Comment: If the output of _o1_ and _o2_ must be on the same line then use Console.Write instead of WriteLine